# Как переместить папку в laravel используя Storage?

Tags: php, laravel

Как переместить папку с подпапками и файлами в ларавел используя `Storage`?

```
Storage::move('old/file1.jpg', 'new/file1.jpg');
```

Вроде только работает с файлами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storage` не поддерживает перенос папок. Нужно использовать `moveDirectory`

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$file = new Filesystem();
$file->moveDirectory('../storage/app/public/old_folder', '../storage/app/public/new_folder');
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_moveDirectory)

Comment: в ответе не работает почему-то

Comment: @Pupsik вы дали точно такой же ответ) Как он может не работать)

Comment: @Pupsik ну и код я взял с действующего проекта. всё нормально.

Comment: у меня в папке storage/app/public/0'.Auth::user()->id есть 5 фото и папка small в которой так же 5 миниатюр, но не перемещает

Comment: @Pupsik включите дебаг и посмотрите какая ошибка. Также проверьте, есть ли права на работу с папками. Но код должен работать.

Comment: в том то и дело что ошибки нет